# Pagination3 - RemoteMediator.load() with refresh request from UI

Tags: android, android-paging-3

I have been working on Pagination3 in Android.
I use [initialize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/RemoteMediator.InitializeAction?authuser=3#SKIP_INITIAL_REFRESH) method to display old cached data on app start.

```
override suspend fun initialize(): InitializeAction {
        return InitializeAction.SKIP_INITIAL_REFRESH
    }
```

it says "Wait for a refresh request from the UI before dispatching `load` with load type `REFRESH`" but I can't find a way to request refresh load from the UI.
I will appreciate it if you point out where to find the solution for this type of explanation from official document. Or just an answer will be appreciated too.
Thank you in advance.